# Single Line Nested For Loops in Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm having some trouble understanding how nested single line for loops work. Here's an example:

I have this code:

```
NewArray = np.array([ get_position(i, size-1, t) for i in range(0, size)])
```

and I'm trying to rewrite this to:

```
for i in range(0,size):
      NewArray = np.array([ get_position(i, size-1, t)])
```

But I'm getting different outputs, so I'm guessing there's a logic error here.

Could you point out the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the first one creates a numpy array containing all your values (you create all values because you're using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) and the second one creates a new array containing the last value each iteration (and it discards the array created in the last iteration because you reuse the same name).

You could rewrite the second one as:

```
lst = []
for i in range(0,size):
    lst.append(get_position(i, size-1, t))
NewArray = np.array(lst)
```

that should give the same result as your first operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the first you create an array of length `size`.
In the second you repeatedly (`size` times) create an array of length `1`.